# Exclude Dates from Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I want to exclude certain dates in the below query how would i do this.  I want to exclude dates like 25/12/2014.

```
SELECT *,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, [1], next_service)) - (DATEDIFF(wk, [1], next_service) * 2) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [1]) = 'Sunday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [1]) = 'Saturday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS days_diff_1,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, [2], next_service)) - (DATEDIFF(wk, [2], next_service) * 2) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [2]) = 'Sunday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [2]) = 'Saturday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS days_diff_2,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, [3], next_service)) - (DATEDIFF(wk, [3], next_service) * 2) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [3]) = 'Sunday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, [3]) = 'Saturday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS days_diff_3,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, u_gas_injunction, next_service)) - (DATEDIFF(wk, u_gas_injunction, next_service) * 2) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, u_gas_injunction) = 'Sunday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) - (
        CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(dw, u_gas_injunction) = 'Saturday'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS injunction_diff,
    DATEADD(day, (- 25 % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, next_service) + (25 % 5)) % 7)
            WHEN 0
                THEN 2
            WHEN 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END, DATEADD(week, (- 25 / 5), next_service)) AS apt_target1,
    DATEADD(day, (- 18 % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, next_service) + (18 % 5)) % 7)
            WHEN 0
                THEN 2
            WHEN 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END, DATEADD(week, (- 18 / 5), next_service)) AS apt_target2,
    DATEADD(day, (- 8 % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, next_service) + (8 % 5)) % 7)
            WHEN 0
                THEN 2
            WHEN 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END, DATEADD(week, (- 8 / 5), next_service)) AS apt_target3,
    DATEADD(day, (- 5 % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, next_service) + (5 % 5)) % 7)
            WHEN 0
                THEN 2
            WHEN 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END, DATEADD(week, (- 5 / 5), next_service)) AS injunction_targe
FROM #rk_ap_pivot
```

Comment: First, take a look [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `WHERE datefield <> '2014-12-25'` after `FROM #rk_ap_pivot`.

Comment: I think the OP should take a little time to read about the `WHERE` clause since it is basic knowledge of `SQL`, rather than receiving an answer on a golden platter. Looking at the degree of complexity of the query I can only assume that it was a "*COPY-PASTE and ask*" type of question, with little or no effort from his side. We need to teach new StackOverflow users how to behave and how to ask questions in this community. Just listen to the man, [**here**](http://youtu.be/kzrz-hGr2bw?t=1m21s), giving guidelines on how to ask questions.

Comment: This is not working not sure if I explained correctly.  The following is calculating the number of days (DATEDIFF(dd, [1], next_service) ) - (DATEDIFF(wk, [1], next_service) * 2) - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [1]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [1]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as days_diff_1 and within this I would like to exclude certain dates so I get the working days only.